# Argument of type 'Partial<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'

Tags: typescript

I wan to be able to call my function like `do({prop: 'value'});`so I had this signature:

```
  public do(data: Partial<T>): void {
    thirdParty.process(T); //<-- Argument of type 'Partial<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  }
```

Any ideas how to fix?

Comment: Sounds like the argument to ` thirdParty.process` has a type of `T`, so you cannot pass a partial `T` as an argument.

Comment: If you replace `Partial<T>` with just `T`, does the error go away?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Argument of type 'Partial' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.

This is correct and is identifying a bug.

To illustrate with a simpler case:

```
interface Foo { a: number, b: number }

const wholeFoo: Foo = { a: 1, b: 2 } // Works
const partialFoo: Partial<Foo> = { a: 1 } // Works

const anotherWholeFoo: Foo = partialFoo
// error: a & b could be undefined but both are required
```

This example fails because `Foo` requires a value for `a` and `b`, but `Partial<Foo>` allows both to be omitted.

The "fix" here is to implement how you get from a `Partial<T>`, to a full `T` will all properties present.

I have no idea what your data looks like but that might be something like:

```
public do(wholeData: T, newData: Partial<T>): void {
  thirdParty.process({ ...wholeData, ...newData });
}
```